# org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException org.springframework.beans.factory.NoUniqueBeanDefinitionException

Tags: java, spring

Como resolver ambiguedades en la **CONEXION AUTOMATICA** de Bean en Spring?
Imagenemos que tenemos una interfaz Postre, y tenemos tres postres diferentes (Beans) que implementan la interfaz(Dessert).

El postre del dia es Cookie, por lo tanto lo anotamos como favorito con `@Primary`.

El problema, es que se han hecho los postres justos y si alguien quiere repetir postre, no habra mas Cookies, por lo que hemos creado "repeatDessert" para aquellos que quieran repetir postre.

Ademas del postre favorito, existen dos postres mas, CAKE Y ICECREAM.

Queremos que a todos los que repitan se le sirva de postre IceCream, del que tenemos cantidad suficiente.

¿como podemos decirle a Spring cual de los dos postres es que el queremos que sirva?

```
public interface Dessert {
    void eat();
}
```

BEAN CAKE:

```
@Component
public class Cake implements Dessert{

    private Dessert repeatDessert;

    public Dessert getRepeatDessert() {
        return repeatDessert;
    }

    @Autowired
    public void setRepeatDessert(Dessert repeatDessert) {
       this.repeatDessert = repeatDessert;
    }

    @Override
    public void eat() {
        System.out.println("Eating a Cake !!!!");
    }
}
```

BEAN COOKIE:

```
@Component
@Primary
public class Cookie implements Dessert{

    private Dessert repeatDessert;

    public Dessert getRepeatDessert() {
        return repeatDessert;
    }

    @Autowired
    public void setRepeatDessert(Dessert repeatDessert) {
       this.repeatDessert = repeatDessert;
    }

    @Override
    public void eat() {
        System.out.println("Eating a Cookie !!!!");
    }
}
```

BEAN ICECREAM:

```
@Component
public class IceCream implements Dessert{

    private Dessert repeatDessert;

    public Dessert getRepeatDessert() {
        return repeatDessert;
    }

    @Autowired
    public void setRepeatDessert(Dessert repeatDessert) {
       this.repeatDessert = repeatDessert;
    }

    @Override
    public void eat() {
        System.out.println("Eating a IceCream !!!!");
    }
}
```

Este seria el archivo de configuracion:

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan
public class AutoBeanConfiguration {

}
```

Esta seria la clase Main:

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        BasicConfigurator.configure();
        Logger.getRootLogger().setLevel(Level.ERROR);
        AnnotationConfigApplicationContext ctxt = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(AutoBeanConfiguration.class);
        Cookies cookies = ctxt.getBean(Cookies.class);
        cookies.eat();
        Dessert dessert = cookies.getRepeatDessert();
        dessert.eat();
        ctxt.close();
    }

}
```

El programa arroja la siguiente `excepcion`:

```
Exception in thread "main" Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'cookies': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'setRepeatDessert' parameter 0;
org.springframework.beans.factory.NoUniqueBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'Dessert' available: expected single matching bean but found 2: cake,iceCream
```

Como podemos resolver la ambiguedad y decirle a spring cual de los Postres queremos que cree, cuando queremos repetir?

La salida por consola deberia ser esta:

```
Eating a Cookies !!!!
Eating a IceCream !!!!
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Como bien aparece en el error, tu fallo es que al intentar inyectar un `Dessert` en `setRepeatingDessert`, Spring no sabe a qué implementación de `Dessert`te refieres.

Puedes arreglarlo utilizando [`@Qualifier`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/annotation/Qualifier.html), que te permite especificar qué bean quieres que se inyecte. Por defecto, utiliza el nombre de la clase del bean en lowerCamelCase, como si se tratase de una variable:

```
@Autowired
public void setRepeatingDessert(@Qualifier("iceCream") Dessert repeatingDessert) {
    this.repeatingDessert = repeatingDessert;
}

Cookie dessert = ctxt.getBean(Cookie.class);

System.out.println(dessert.eat());  // "Eating cake!!"
System.out.println(dessert.getRepeatingDessert().eat()); // "Eating ice cream!!"
```

También puedes ponerle a tu bean un nombre personalizado, de nuevo con la etiqueta `@Qualifier`, esta vez en la declaración de la clase:

```
@Component
@Qualifier("remainingDessert")
public class IceCream implements Dessert{

    // Clase IceCream
}
```

Pero entonces recuerda que el calificador que usas en el punto de inyección ha de estar acorde:

```
@Autowired
public void setRepeatingDessert(@Qualifier("remainingDessert") Dessert repeatingDessert) {
    this.repeatingDessert = repeatingDessert;
}

Cookie dessert = ctxt.getBean(Cookie.class);

System.out.println(dessert.eat());  // "Eating cake!!"
System.out.println(dessert.getRepeatingDessert().eat()); // "Eating ice cream!!"
```